# sys/kernel/debug/krpobes/list empty

Tags: kernel, trace, kprobe

I'm trying to attach to a kprobe event for purposes of tooling, but I'm not too familiar with kprobe events. I've read that the list of registered kprobes are available in `/sys/kernel/debug/kprobes/list` however `sudo less /sys/kernel/debug/krpobes/list` shows that there are no registered kprobes. I've confirmed that krpobes/enabled is 1. Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/sys/kernel/debug/kprobes/list` has **the list of registered kprobes, not available kprobe hooks** (cf. the `The kprobes debugfs interface` section of [the kprobes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt)).

I don't think there's a list of available kprobe hooks somewhere. However, `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/available_filter_functions` has a list of **kprobe hooks available through ftrace**. Most available functions should be in there. Otherwise, you can check the list of complete exposed functions in `/proc/kallsyms` and verify they are not blacklisted in `/sys/kernel/debug/krpobes/blacklist`. If a function is not in `/proc/kallsyms`, it's likely because is was inlined at compile time.

> Am I doing something horribly wrong?

So, no, nothing horrible :-)